# Unity Building Linux Il2CPP player requires a sysroot toolchain package to be installed

Tags: linux, unity-game-engine, il2cpp

For some reason I'm unable to build an IL2CPP Linux build in unity. 
I used to be able to build IL2CPP Linux builds fine on the same machine using the same version of unity, but it recently stopped working.
This problem occurs in a new project, so I think that this problem doesn't have to do with the project itself.

Unity 2021.3.0f1 LTS (Apple Silicon build)
macOS Monterey 12.2.1

[image: The problem occurs when building "Dedicated Server" builds & "Normal" Linux builds]

[image: Toolchain MacOS Linux x64, Toolchain Win Linux x64, Sysroot Linux x64 and Sysroot base packages are installed and up to date]

[image: Linux IL2CPP module is installed]

[image: Unable to build Linux IL2CPP]

Comment: Well something got updated. Just install it if it’s a requirement

Answer (score 0):

Add the appropriate line to your manifest.json file located in your "packages" folder which is found within the project folder.

**For Below 2020.3:**

**For Linux:** "com.unity.toolchain.linux-x86_64": "1.0.0"

**For Windows:** "com.unity.toolchain.win-x86_64-linux-x86_64": "1.0.0"

**For Mac:** "com.unity.toolchain.macos-x86_64-linux-x86_64": "1.0.0"

---

**Unity 2020.3+:**

**For Linux:** "com.unity.toolchain.linux-x86_64": "2.0.5"

**For Windows:** "com.unity.toolchain.win-x86_64-linux-x86_64": "2.0.5"

**For Mac:** "com.unity.toolchain.macos-x86_64-linux-x86_64": "2.0.5"

*If you have errors with v2.0.5 change the package version until the errors clear with your installed version of unity.*

Solved via - [https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/hub-editor-is-unable-to-locate-the-linux-il2cpp-module-when-installed-through-unity-hub#:~:text=%5BHub%5D%20Editor%20is%20unable%20to%20locate%20the%20Linux,x64%20package%204%204.%20Go%20to%20Build%20Settings](https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/hub-editor-is-unable-to-locate-the-linux-il2cpp-module-when-installed-through-unity-hub#:%7E:text=%5BHub%5D%20Editor%20is%20unable%20to%20locate%20the%20Linux,x64%20package%204%204.%20Go%20to%20Build%20Settings)